# Unpack fields from IBM data file

Tags: perl, unpack, ebcdic

I have an EBCDIC-encoded data file from an IBM mainframe source that needs to be parsed and converted to ASCII. I was able to convert by reading it per byte in hexadecimal and look for corresponding matches on ASCII.

My issue is that the EBCDIC-encoded file there are 30 bytes that are packed and need to be unpacked to get the actual values. I am trying out ways using PHP pack/unpack function as well as with Perl but found no luck. The value that I am getting doesn't seem to be the exact value that I am looking for. I tried unpacking it with C c H h N.

Assuming that file holds an EBCDIC encoded data;
pack fields are on position 635-664, 30 bytes long
    data1 = 9 bytes
    data2 = 9 bytes
    data3 = 3 bytes
    data4 = 3 bytes
    data5 = 3 bytes
    data6 = 3 bytes

PHP:

```
     $datafile = fopen("/var/www/data/datafile", "rb");
     $regebcdicdata = fread($datafile, 634);
     $packfields = fread($datafile, 30);
     $arr= unpack('c9data1/c9bdata2/c3data3/C3data4/C3data5/C3data6',$packfields);
     print_r($arr);
```

PERL:

```
    open my $fh, '<:raw', '/var/www/html/PERL/test';
    my $bytes_read = read $fh, my $bytes, 634;
    my $bytes_read2 = read $fh, my $bytes2, 30;
    my ($data1,$data2,$data3,$data4,$data5,$data6) = unpack 'C9 C9 C3 C3 C3 C3',     $bytes2;
```

UPDATE:
Already found a solution. Those 30 bytes were packed in a specified format. So I just unpack using PHP unpack function.

For EBCDIC conversion. I read it per byte, get the hexadecimal value using bin2hex() function, find matching ASCII hexadecimal value and get the ASCII representation so user can see it in readable format using chr() function.

I used conversion table at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.3.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.adref.doc/topics/r_deeadvrf_ASCII_and_EBCDIC_Conversion_Tables.html.

Comment: You need to include the data, otherwise no-one will be able to try for you. You should also include the actual code that you've already tried. [Edit] the question and add that please.

Comment: I can't include the data because of confidentiality. However, I can give you the code I've used both in Perl and PHP.

Answer (score 3):

I can't possibly help you to unpack those thirty bytes without knowing how they have been packed. Surely you must have some idea?

As for the regular EBCDIC text, you need to establish exactly which code page your document uses, and then you can simply use Perl IO to decode it

Suppose you are dealing with [code page 37](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_037), then you can open your file like this

```
open my $fh, '<:encoding(cp37)', 'ebcdic_file' or die $!
```

and then you can read the data as normal. It will be retrieved as Unicode characters

Comment: Great! Thanks. So I need to check on on them how this data have been packed. I edited my post with the code I used. Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: @user3472277 what Borodin is saying is that there is no need to `unpack` if you know what the data is because they are not really packed, they just have weird encoding. Find out what encoding it is, and Perl can read it for you automatically.

Comment: @simbabque: From the OP's code it looks like there are 634 bytes of EBCDIC-encoded characters, followed by 30 bytes of something else. Whether that is really packed or not I cannot tell.

Comment: @simbabque Yes I got it!. But my client said that on position 635-664 which is 30 bytes. Those are packed which is needed to be unpack to get their actual values. Please refer to my post. I already edited it. Thanks :) Expected actual values are in numeric format.

Comment: @user3472277: Your Perl code is unusual but looks basically okay. Your `unpack` call us wrong, but until we find out what is in those thirty bytes I cannot tell you what would be correct.

Comment: @user3472277: It is meaningless to say that the field is "packed" without saying *how*. It is impossible to help you until you discover that information.

Comment: @user3472277  does your client know what data is supposed to be there?

Comment: @Borodin Thanks, maybe I can tell, within that 30 bytes is a phonenumber 9 in length, phone number 9 in length, position of lastname 3 in length, position of firstname 3 in length, position of middlename 3 in length and position of suffix 3 in length. These are all numeric data . This are the expected values.

Comment: I suspect that those thirty characters are just a sequence of decimal digits, probably EBCDIC-encoded, which happens to correspond to six decimal numbers without any separators.

Comment: @user3472277: You still haven't told use *how they are packed*. If you won't find that out and won't show us the data then it's impossible to help you beyond the guesses I've already made.

Comment: @user3472277: The primary purpose of any page on Stack Overflow is not to get you an answer to your question, but to help the dozens of people who will come here looking for help with something similar. If you have a solution then please don't keep it to yourself, but post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

This is wild guess, as I know neither which EBCDIC code page you are using nor how the thirty bytes are packed. But there is a slim chance that it will do what you want

Please try running this program and tell us the results

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my @data = do {
    open my $fh, '<:encoding(cp37)', '/var/www/html/PERL/test' or die $!;
    local $/;
    my $data = <$fh>;
    unpack '@634 A9 A9 A3 A3 A3 A3', $data;
};

say for @data;
```